# I am trying to display two images one a map icon and the other an amenities icon 2 seperate photos. I have tried many different ways

Tags: html

`enter code here`I am working on a program for RVers that travel full time.  I am trying to a google map icon and when you mouse over it displays a map of the state where the rv park is at. I also want a second button for amenaties of the park and when you mouse over the button a photo of the amenities will pop up.  This code works for one button.  I have tried every thing i know to get both to work.  please advise.`

```
   `<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Image hover demo</title>
 <style>
  #img2{
    position: fixed;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    display: none;
  }
  </style>
  </head>

<body>
<img id="img1" src="http://fbook123.com/smf/images/gmap.png" />
<img id="img2" src="http://fbook123.com/smf/images/hidencovemap.png" />

<script>
  var img1 = document.getElementById("img1"),
      img2 = document.getElementById("img2");

  img1.onmouseover = function(){
    img2.style.display = "block";
  }

  img1.onmouseout = function(){
    img2.style.display = "none";
  }
  </script>
 </body>  `
```

Comment: The code above works but will only do one button and display the map on mouseover, I need it to also display an amenities button amenbut.png and when you mouse over it a img  of the amenities  hcamen.png  will show also just like the map does.

Comment: you should show proof of the "I have tried every thing i know to get both to work" part

Answer (score -1):

I solved this error by using an attribute to the source.

Change the HTML to:

```
<img id="img1" 
    src="http://fbook123.com/smf/images/gmap.png" 
    onmouseover="document.getElementById("img2").style.display = 'block';"
    onmouseleave="document.getElementById("img2").style.display = 'none';"
/>
<img id="img2" src="http://fbook123.com/smf/images/hidencovemap.png" />
```

Then you can erase the script part which reduces the code.

Comment: I tried this and the map stays on all the time.